# How to print only output and not the command-line on terminal in makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

I want write simple "help" options to my makefile,but the problem is 
for example;

```
all: 
   echo "help options.."
```

when I call `make` on terminal,it print:

```
echo "help options.."
help options..
```

it's possible print only?:

```
help options..
```

I hope this is clear for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefix the command by '@', as in:

```
target:
    @echo "help options.."
```

GNU Make has a very good [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing) which explains this.

Comment: Tip: you can add `@` at the top line of the commands to avoid add it to every line head.